# Send data from Activity to Class extent Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have code in Activity using ViewPager

```
//mycode
public class ViewPagerActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapterHehe mAdapter1;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = {"Feed", "Search", "Status"};
    Toast mToast = null;
    // set ActionBar;
    private LinearLayout layout_btn_search, layout_image_view, layout_edt_search, layout_btn_logout;
    private EditText edt_search_1;
    String key_word;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_pager);

        // check internet cho app
        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
        isInternetPresent = cd.checkMobileInternetConn();

        // isOnline
        boolean b = isOnline();
        if (isOnline()) {
            setActionBar();
            // Initilization
            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            actionBar = getActionBar();
            mAdapter1 = new TabsPagerAdapterHehe(getSupportFragmentManager());
            viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter1);
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
         actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

            // Adding Tabs
            for (String tab_name : tabs) {
                actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                        .setTabListener(ViewPagerActivity.this));
            }

            /**
             * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
             * */
            viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    // on changing the page
                    // make respected tab selected
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(ViewPagerActivity.this, "ネットワーク環境がありません", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    // show dialog check Internet cho app
    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        hideSoftKeyboard();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        layout_edt_search.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        layout_btn_search.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        edt_search_1.setText("");
        hideSoftKeyboard();
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        boolean b = isOnline();
        if (isOnline()) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        } else {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            Toast.makeText(ViewPagerActivity.this, "ネットワーク環境がありません", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        hideSoftKeyboard();
    }
    // set ActionBar
    private void setActionBar() {
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);


        edt_search_1.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                    // hide keyboard
                          Bundle b = new Bundle();
                            key_word = edt_search_1.getText().toString();
                            b.putString("keyword", keyword);
                            FragmentSearch fgsearch = new FragmentSearch();
                            fgsearch.setArguments(b);
                            Log.e("KEYWORD", key_word);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "HEHE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
            }

        });
        actionBar.setCustomView(mView);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    }

    /// do Search
    private void doSeachNew() {



    }


    private class TabsPagerAdapterHehe extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public TabsPagerAdapterHehe(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }


        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {

            switch (i) {
                case 1:
                    return new FragmentSearch();
                case 2:
                    return new New_Status();
                default:
                    return new HomeTimelineFragment();
                //return new FragmentHomeTimeLine();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }
    }

    public void hideSoftKeyboard() {
        if (getCurrentFocus() != null) {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        //  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public static class CheckNetwork {


        static String TAG = CheckNetwork.class.getSimpleName();


        public static boolean isInternetAvailable(Context context) {
            NetworkInfo info = (NetworkInfo) ((ConnectivityManager)
                    context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if (info == null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "no internet connection");
                return false;
            } else {
                if (info.isConnected()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, " internet connection available...");
                    return true;
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, " internet connection");
                    return true;
                }

            }
        }
    }

}
```

And Class My Fragment

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_list, container, false);
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    keyword = bundle.getString("keyword");
    Log.e("KeyWord", keyword);
    return view;
}
```

And this is my bug

```
10-21 14:11:26.639    7278-7278/vn.seesaa.nguyentrunghieu.logintwitter E/SetSizeByPercent﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
10-21 14:11:26.709    7278-7278/vn.seesaa.nguyentrunghieu.logintwitter E/client﹕ vn.seesaa.nguyentrunghieu.client.TwitterClient@44a626e0
10-21 14:11:26.849    7278-7278/vn.seesaa.nguyentrunghieu.logintwitter E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: vn.seesaa.nguyentrunghieu.logintwitter, PID: 7278
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at vn.seesaa.nguyentrunghieu.viewpager.FragmentSearch.onCreateView(FragmentSearch.java:73)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1026)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1207)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1572)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:545)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1474)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16628)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16628)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16628)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16628)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16628)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2298)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16628)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1920)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1117)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1299)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5692)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5151)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please! Help me fix bug!!
Thanks you very much!

Comment: where do you setarguments in fragment

Comment: switch (i) {
            case 1:
                return new FragmentSearch();

**here add the arguments like this :**
Bundle b = new Bundle();
key_word = edt_search_1.getText().toString();
b.putString("keyword", "hello");
FragmentSearch fgsearch = new FragmentSearch();
fgsearch.setArguments(b);
**and return fgsearch in getItem()**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you should change your scheme of creating Fragment instance? For example, in Android Studio when you want to create new BlankFragment without any callbacks but with fragment factory method, it generates this:

```
/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link BlankFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;


    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment BlankFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static BlankFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    }
}
```

In your case, your ARG_PARAM1 is "keyword". And all is your need - create fragment with factory method, like this:

```
BlankFragment fragment = BlankFragment.newInstance("hello")
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I try it!. It worked!. But It just work with "hello". I want input data on Edittext.
Please! help me!

Comment: Glad to see it. But what is your problem? Before creating an instance of Fragment, just get value from your edittext, e.g. 

String value = editText.getText();

Then pass this value to factory method:

BlankFragment fragment = BlankFragment.newInstance(value);

Comment: I have a Viewpager. It have 3 tab. Feed, Search, Status.
I set a Actionbar in Viewpager is setActionbar method   ( my code )
In method setActionbar. I have a Edittext. When I enter data on Edittext. I want show data on tab Search.

Please! Can You help me!

Comment: Your code! When I run application. It worked!.
I want application work after I enter data on Edittext and tab icon search on keyboard!

Comment: Excuse me, but I really don't understand what do you want to do. On one tab you have EditText and you want see inputed text on another tab?.. Then just save text in some variable and in the pageSelectedListener change text of anything you want. 
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your `getItem()` method, you are returning a new instance of the fragment.

```
return new FragmentSearch();
```

In this case, there is no arguments set for the fragment. Hence calling `getArguments()` will return null. Hence the nullpointerexception.

Just do a null check there.

**UPDATE**: If you just want the exception to go away the below is the fix. If you care about the arguments passed, then you need to `setArguments()` for the created `FragmentSearch` in the `getItem()` method.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_list, container, false);
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if(bundle != null){
       keyword = bundle.getString("keyword");
       Log.e("KeyWord", keyword);
    }
    return view;
}
```

**Best Practice:**
Always use the `onCreateView()` just to inflate the layout and return it. All other piece of code should be put in the `onActivityCreated()` callback.